# Как в Android Studio по нажатию кнопки выводить свой текст в TextView?

Tags: android, activity

Вот у меня обработчик события onClick на изображение. Мне надо в элементе Textview свой текст вставить по нажатию! Почему у меня не получается? Я уже все перепробовал и объявлял переменную типа TextView, но он подчеркивал красным цветом TextView.

```
package com.example.dasha;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Hello Kitty!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```